# Computer randomly freezing at different times

Tags: windows-10, amd-radeon

I am running Windows 10 on a computer with a MSI 990fxa gaming motherboard, amd fx-9590 cpu, a nzxt kraken x61 cpu liquid cooler, xfx r9 290x 8gb gpu, a 1tb ssd, 2 2TB hdds in raid 0, and a 1000watt psu. Before I had the cooler I underclocked the CPU so that I could run it just fine. Now that it isn't underclock ed and I have the cooler it seems to freeze like it did when I didn't have the cooler and the CPU wasn't underclocked. I know the CPU and gpu aren't getting too hot so what else is there that it could be? I thought maybe the PSU wasn't powerful enough since the CPU is asking for 200w rather than 190 but I'm not sure. Any ideas?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What temperature is the CPU running?

Comment: @acejavelin The CPU topped at 46 degrees Celsius while playing a game when it froze at one point. Other times it freezes when it is in the low twenties. It's not the cpu.

Comment: And it's not power... 1000w PS should be more than adequate for that rig. RAM? Have you tried MemTest86?

Comment: @acejavelin are you sure it wouldn't be the power? Forgot to mention 32 GB of ram. After using tools on newegg I seem really close to the limit. But I have not tried memtest86. I will give that a shot and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Not likely power, unless your PS is not working properly or rated incorrectly (many cheap, generic PS are very liberal with their ratings). Based on the video card and stated hardware, the minimum PS requirement in this configuration is around 750 watts, with 850 watts recommended, you are at a 1000... Using this tool: http://outervision.com/power-supply-calculator your configuration requires around 755w, and I was liberal and included several USB peripherals, multiple BluRay drives, a BitCoin mining module, 3-120mm fans, and a standalone SATA raid controller.

Comment: @acejavelin I see what you meqn. I just tried it out too and I should have plenty of power. I am running memtest86 right now. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: @acejavelin The ram passed with no errors. I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: What causes the freeze or when does it occur? Anything in event logs right before freeze occurs?

Comment: @acejavelin It started when I got the new cpu. It happens a couple minutes after logging into windows no matter what I am doing at the time. I have read a lot about the 9590 being unstable and just using too much power so I have decided to just take it back and go back to an 8350.

Comment: do you have the latest BIOS for your motherboard and doesn't specifically say it supports that CPU?

Comment: @acejavelin Yes. The motherboard required v1.1 for the cpu but I have v1.4.

Comment: Well, the 8350 is a more stable CPU, still wonder what the issue is... Does your 5v and 12v motherboard rails have enough current?

Comment: @acejavelin I would assume so.